# Android Studio did not open any file in windows

Tags: android, android-studio

My android studio did not open any single file, But it open the total project in left tab and shows all file name. But when I click on any file name as usual then it did not work or open and it became  freezes.

> I restart my laptop multiple times and sync Project many times, close
> the project and start the project more than one times.

Please help me...

Comment: Try to create new project and copy all files here

Comment: I just uninstall the Android studio and reinstall it. Now it works fine.Thanks for your comment.